# MacBookAir7,2 suddenly lags after updating to Monterey

Tags: macos

I have a MacBookAir7,2 that's been with me since around 2016/2017. I don't remember the exact year.

It has a Dual-Core Intel Core i5 processor at 1.6GHz. It used to have High Sierra version then I upgraded it to Monterey 12.6.0 just few days ago.

It started all good with Monterey but now started lagging ever since I installed the 12.6.1 update.

I tried updating it to version 12.6.1 but it seems to get stuck at **15 minutes** remaining. Not really getting through the update.

How to fix the lagging issue of MacOS 12.6.0? Is this one of those planned obsolescense?

Comment: disable all your 32 bit apps, un-instal or get 64 bit versions

Comment: Where did you get these information?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208436

Answer (score 2):

**Is this one of those planned obsolescence?**

No. If you Mac is supported by a new OS, then it should work, and it should work well. *(If Apple can't get an OS to run well on a Mac model, then they exclude it from the OS.)*

Problems after upgrading are often caused by third-party software that is incompatible with the new OS. It may need upgrading, or removing.

Jumping several 'years' in one go is more likely to make this happen.

I would recommend using an app like EtreCheck, which provides you with a report of all the software that might affect system performance. You can then check whether you need everything it lists, or whether it needs updating to a newer version.

https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html

You can post the report here, in your question, if you'd like. It does not contain any identifying or unique information.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245), then booting again normally.  This will flush various caches and is always a good troubleshooting step.

Then open System Preferences > Users & Groups, and try removing all entries from the Login Items section.  Log out and log back in and see if the lagging behavior persists.